# How do i append a new row of strings(data) with a new "index number" next to the row in a text file

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I want to append a new row as well as a new index number to a text file using stream writer or any method in vb.net(i am using the 2015 version)
I managed to get it to save but it only saves the first textbox.
this is what I have so far :

```
    Dim outputFile As IO.StreamWriter
    Dim filePath As String = "PCPT2Database.txt"
    Dim intNewNo() As Integer = {}
    Dim intCount As Integer = 0
    Dim currentRow() As String

    Dim intLoop As Integer

    Using MyReader As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser(filePath)
        MyReader.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
        MyReader.SetDelimiters(",")

        While Not MyReader.EndOfData
            Try
                currentRow = MyReader.ReadFields()

                ReDim Preserve intNewNo(intCount)

                intNewNo(intCount) = currentRow(0)

                intCount = +1

            Catch ex As Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.MalformedLineException
                MsgBox("line" & ex.Message & " Its not valid.")

            End Try
        End While
    End Using

    For intLoop = 0 To intCount + 1

    Next




    If IO.File.Exists(filePath) = True Then
        outputFile = IO.File.AppendText(filePath)

        outputFile.WriteLine(intNewNo(intLoop), txtName.Text, txtSurname.Text, mtbCell.Text, txtEmail.Text)
        'intNewNo(intLoop),
        MessageBox.Show("Save Successful")
        outputFile.Close()

        MessageBox.Show("Add another record", "Cancel", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Information)

        txtName.Clear()
        txtSurname.Clear()
        mtbCell.Clear()
        txtEmail.Clear()
    Else
        MessageBox.Show(filePath, ".txt not found.", _
                        MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Any help would be appreciated. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `outputFile` declaration at the top of your code and use as follows instead:

```
    If IO.File.Exists(filePath) Then

        Using outputFile = IO.File.AppendText(filePath)
            outputFile.WriteLine(Strings.Join({intNewNo(intLoop).ToString, txtName.Text, txtSurname.Text, mtbCell.Text, txtEmail.Text}, ","))
        End Using

        
        MessageBox.Show("Save Successful")
        MessageBox.Show("Add another record", "Cancel", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Information)

        txtName.Clear()
        txtSurname.Clear()
        mtbCell.Clear()
        txtEmail.Clear()
    Else
        MessageBox.Show(filePath, ".txt not found.",
                        MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    End If
```

However your code need to be optimized (a bit ?) (: